# incrontab is not recognizing www-data writes

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, incrontab

I have a Linux server with incrontab.
Here is my incrontab

/home/pi/upload IN_MODIFY /bin/sh /home/pi/autoprint $@/$#

If I am a root user, i tried creating a new pdf file inside the 'upload' folder, and the incrontab event is triggered,, however, if I upload a file via webserver

`http://127.0.0.1/upload.php`, a new file is created inside the 'upload' folder,, but the event is not triggered

[image]

all root created files,, are recognized and triggers the incrontab script,,, but those created by 'www-data' are not triggered..

Why is that so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved. Take note that when uploading files,,, PHP first uploads them into a temporary folder, and then it moves the file toward the directory you specified.

Making the trigger 'IN_MOVED' solved the problem.